# How to redirect back to form with input - Laravel 5

Tags: php, forms, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

How do I redirect back to my form page, with the given `POST` params, if my form action throws an exception?

Comment: You know I had to upvote your question only because you asked and answered it at the same time.

Comment: Thought it'd be helpful for other folks. Couldn't find the solution so i dug through the source to see how it's handled with Form Validation automatically

Comment: I always appreciate it.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can use the following:

```php
return Redirect::back()->withInput(Input::all());
```

If you're using [Form Request Validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation), this is exactly how Laravel will redirect you back with errors and the given input.

Excerpt from [`\Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ebd86d7d2ff4e34b24a0dd84d10bb77c13130222/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.php#L123-L125):

> ```
> return redirect()->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
>                     ->withInput($request->input())
>                     ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag());
> ```

Comment: No, it does not maintain your input params

Comment: Sure, I ment this: `return redirect()->back()->withInput();` It's just a handy macro.

Comment: you should know that you will need this in your form `<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
`  as @Vishal_Rambhiya responded

Answer (score 68):

write old function  on your fields value
for example

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
```

Comment: Thanks ! I am using Laravel 5.2 and this works for me too . Along with `old()` function in our blade template , we also need to use `withInput()` in our controller to make it work . Like => 


`if($validate->fails()) 
    return  redirect("somepage")->withErrors($validate)->withInput();`

Comment: Any idea on how to do this for `select`

Comment: @NiteshVerma you can use jquery like `{{if(isset(old('select')){'$("select option[value=\''.old('select').'\']").attr("selected",true)'}};`

Comment: Is there any solution similar to this for Laravel 4.2?

Comment: how to do this on the select box ?

Comment: forgot to do this :) wanted laravel to magiccally show errors

Answer (score 34):

In your HTML you have to use `value = {{ old('') }}`. Without using it, you can't get the value back because what session will store in their cache.

Like for a name validation, this will be-

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" />
```

Now, you can get the value after submitting it if there is error with redirect.

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

As ***@infomaniac*** says, you can also use the `Input class` directly,

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput(Input::all());
```

**Add:**
If you only show the specific field, then use `$request->only()`

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('name'));
```

**Update:**
Get more example and real-life demonstration of Laravel form input here - https://devsenv.com/tutorials/how-to-redirect-back-in-laravel-with-form-input-and-many-possible-ways

Hope, it might work in all case, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

**this will work definately** !!!

```
  $validation = Validator::make($request->all(),[
  'name' => ['Required','alpha']
  ]);
  
   if($validation->passes()){
     print_r($request->name);
   }
   else{
     //this will return the errors & to check put "dd($errors);" in your blade(view)
     return back()->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
   }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use any of these two:

`return redirect()->back()->withInput(Input::all())->with('message', 'Some message');`

Or,

`return redirect('url_goes_here')->withInput(Input::all())->with('message', 'Some message');`

Comment: Your answer does not add anything new to previous answers. Also it adds confusion because you do not explain what 'url' is. Also you already made an answer to this question. Please delete one of your answers . You can edit your own previous post.

Answer (score 6):

I handle validation exceptions in Laravel 5.3 like this. If you use Laravel Collective it will automatically display errors next to inputs and if you use laracasts/flash it will also show first validation error as a notice.

---

`Handler.php` render:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException) {
        return $this->handleValidationException($request, $e);
    }

    (..)
}
```

And the function:

```
protected function handleValidationException($request, $e)
    {
        $errors = @$e->validator->errors()->toArray();
        $message = null;
        if (count($errors)) {
            $firstKey = array_keys($errors)[0];
            $message = @$e->validator->errors()->get($firstKey)[0];
            if (strlen($message) == 0) {
                $message = "An error has occurred when trying to register";
            }
        }

        if ($message == null) {
            $message = "An unknown error has occured";
        }

        \Flash::error($message);

        return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::back()->withErrors($e->validator)->withInput();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Laravel 5:

```
return redirect(...)->withInput();
```

for back only:

```
return back()->withInput();
```

Comment: `return back()->withInput();`

Comment: Nice! I was passing `$request->all()` to this method but it's good to know that's not required.

Answer (score 4):

### For Laravel 5

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

### For Laravel 6, 7 and 8

```
return back()->withInput();
```

**Docs**:

- Laravel 5: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects
- Laravel 6: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/responses#redirects
- Laravel 7: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#redirects
- Laravel 8: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirects

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput(Input::all())->with('message', 'Something 
went wrong!');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->flash('request',$request);

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
```

It works for me.