# Laravel validator throws an exception instead of redirecting back

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5, php-5.6

After I upgraded to Laravel 5.2 I encountered a problem with the laravel validator. When I want to validate data in a controller take for example this code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function storeContactRequest(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            '_token' => 'required',
            'firstname' => 'required|string'
            'lastname' => 'required|string'
            'age' => 'required|integer',
            'message' => 'required|string'
        ]);

        // Here to store the message.
    }
}
```

But somehow when I enter unvalid data it will not redirect me back to the previous page and flash some messages to the session but it will trigger an exception and gives me a 500 error page back.

This is the exception I get.
I have read in the documentation that the ValidationException is new instead of the HttpResponseException but I don't know if it has anything to do with this.

```
[2016-01-05 11:49:49] production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidationException' with message 'The given data failed to pass validation.' in /home/vagrant/Code/twentyre-webshop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.php:70
```

And when I use a seperate request class it will just redirect back with the error messages. It seems to me only the validate method used in a controller is affected by this behaviour.

Comment: This is by design. Request classes do the redirect, if you validate manually using ValidatesRequests trait and validate() method you need to catch the exception and handle that yourself.

Comment: But how do I catch the exception when I use it like this in a controller?

Comment: Wrap it in try/catch clause

Comment: Thanks I fixed it I didn't know it was on purpose that it didn't redirect automatically.

Comment: @DB93 How did U solve it? Where did you do redirect?

Comment: @Yurich I did wrap it in a try/catch clause and I redirected in the catch

Comment: This is definitely NOT how it is explained in the doc: `The validate method accepts an incoming HTTP request and a set of validation rules. If the validation rules pass, your code will keep executing normally; however, if validation fails, an exception will be thrown and the proper error response will automatically be sent back to the user. In the case of a traditional HTTP request, a redirect response will be generated, while a JSON response will be sent for AJAX requests.`

Answer (score 3):

Update your `App\Exceptions\Handler` class

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidationException;

/**
 * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dontReport = [
    AuthorizationException::class,
    HttpException::class,
    ModelNotFoundException::class,
    ValidationException::class,
];
```

I also recommend you to read the docs how to migrate to laravel 5.2, because there were some breaking changes. For example this, `ValidatesRequests` trait throws
`Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidationException` instead of `Illuminate\Http\Exception\HttpResponseException`

[Documentation how to migrate from Laravel 5.1 to 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0)

Comment: This won't give the OP the result they need - it won't redirect to previous page and flash validation errors.

Comment: I did add the ValidationException to the dontReport property but it didn't fix my problem. I have read the migration documents and applied all the changes to my project but this is the only thing that is failing for me.

Answer (score 3):

Example from [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators) docs. You can use Validator facade, for custom validation fails behaviour

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('post/create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }

    // Store the blog post...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I handle it in Laravel 5.3 (by modifying `Handler.php`)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42852358/3107185

Answer (score 1):

For laravel 5.2 I had to add this line:

```
    if ($e instanceof ValidationException) 
    {
         return redirect()->back()->withInput();
    }
```

In App\Exceptions\Handler.php,and the following headers:

```
    use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
    use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
    use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
```

Answer (score 0):

For my purpose, I was bulding a fully API based application in **Laravel 5.3** which I had manually upgraded from Laravel 5.1. and I just needed Laravel to respond back with the validation errors that needed fixing on my FormRequest.

Adding this line:

```
elseif ($e instanceof ValidationException) 
 {
        return $this->convertValidationExceptionToResponse($e, $request);
 }
```

after this one:

```
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
    }
```

In `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` did the trick for me and returned expected validation errors when using FormRequest validation.

Please see my comments here: [@ratatatKE's comments on github](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Exceptions/issues/80)

Answer (score 0):

might save someone time, Another issue is that you are calling `validator->validate()` in the view, not in the controller

i was calling in the view because i have a lazy load component that triggered on the view

Answer (score -4):

I had the same problem when upgrading 4.2 to 5.3.

This answer worked for me.

Override the method in app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
protected function convertExceptionToResponse(Exception $e)
{
    if (config('app.debug')) {
        $whoops = new \Whoops\Run;
        $whoops->pushHandler(new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler);

        return response()->make(
            $whoops->handleException($e),
            method_exists($e, 'getStatusCode') ? $e->getStatusCode() : 500,
            method_exists($e, 'getHeaders') ? $e->getHeaders() : []
        );
    }

    return parent::convertExceptionToResponse($e);
}
```

Answer found here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/whoops-20-laravel-52

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I had the same problem as the question.  "Laravel validator throws an exception instead of redirecting back".  That's the problem I was having.  I fixed it with the solution above. There might be more than one cause for this error therefore more than one answer.  I posted to help someone who is struggling with this error like I was.