# How to use return back()->withInput() in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

i always get error like this when i use withInput() function in return back()
but when i dont use withInput() this error wont appear.

> ErrorException in helpers.php line 469: htmlentities() expects
>   parameter 1 to be string, array given

this the validation code

```
$validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name'         => 'required|unique:products', 
    'category_id'  => 'required', 
    'region'       => 'required', 
    'primary_image'=> 'required'
]);

if($validation->fails()) {
    return back()->withInput()
        ->with('error', 'Please upload the image!');
```

and for the view, this is the full trace code:
https://thepasteb.in/p/pghNcGOzPAqZncN

i want when the validation is fail, it will back with previous input.
hope you can give me solution :)
thankyou.

Comment: Could you try to pinpoint the exact location of the error? Because the error is thrown in helpers.php, but that's not where the error began.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan the complete error message is htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /home/faisal/wgs/paskomnasdev/paskomnas/resources/views/admin/product/create.blade.php),,,,and the blade is on thepasteb.in

Comment: Have you tried using ..`->withInput($request->all())->with(....)` Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081644/how-to-redirect-back-to-form-with-input-laravel-5

Comment: @FaisalHilmi at what line in that view are you getting the error?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan i dont know, but i just try to remove all input form except the form::text('name') and its worked

Comment: @vijayrana oke i will try, edited, i use $request->all() and still not working :(

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to try this:

```
 if($validation->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator) ->withInput();
  }
```

OR

```
 if($validation->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('error', 'Please upload the image!');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use this, and it works for me all the time:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Error Message');
```