# Check old data is null or not or check by isset() from input laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel

How can I check old data is available or not after validation from controller? 
i used this but it shows error

```
@if(\Illuminate\Http\Request::old('status')!=null)
    <option style="display: none" value="{{old('status')}}" hidden>{{old('status')}}</option>
@endif
```

also used this one

```
@if(isset(old('status')))
    <option style="display: none" value="{{old('status')}}" hidden>{{old('status')}}</option>
@endif
```

full form is

```
<form action="{{route('add-expense-store')}}" method="post" class="new-added-form">
    {{ @csrf_field() }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-12 form-group">
            <label>Expense Type</label>
            <select class="select2" name="type">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                {{--<option value="Teacher's Salary">Teacher's Salary</option>
                <option value="Staff's Salary">Staff's Salary</option>--}}
                <option value="Transport">Transport</option>
                <option value="Mobile Bill">Mobile Bill</option>
                <option value="Utility Bill">Utility Bill</option>
                <option value="Stationary">Stationary</option>
                <option value="Print & Press">Print & Press</option>
                <option value="Photocopy & Compose">Photocopy & Compose</option>
                <option value="Entertainment & Hospitality">Entertainment & Hospitality</option>
                <option value="Donation">Donation</option>
                <option value="Program">Program</option>
                <option value="Personal or Owner">Personal or Owner</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-12 form-group">
            <label>Status</label>
            <select class="select2" name="status">
                @if(isset(old('status')))
                    <option style="display: none" value="{{old('status')}}" hidden>{{old('status')}}</option>
                @endif
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                <option value="Paid">Paid</option>
                <option value="Due">Due</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-12 form-group">
            <label>Holder Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" name="holder_name"
                   value="{{ old('holder_name') }}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-12 form-group">
            <label>Phone</label>
            <input type="number" placeholder="" class="form-control" name="phone" {{ old('phone') }}>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 form-group mg-t-8">
            <button type="submit" class="btn-fill-lg btn-gradient-yellow btn-hover-bluedark float-right">Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

controller

```
$this->validate($request, [
      'type' => 'required',
      'status' => 'required'
]);
```

both are getting error. How can I check old value us available or not in blade?

Now I include my form data. here I wants to hidden if old value is not found. please help with this one. check isset old data in blade.

Comment: please add controller action which calls render on this view

Comment: after validation I put the old value in blade

Comment: how You put it? that's why I ask You to show controller method

Comment: I edited my question please check

Comment: it's not enough! I asked You whole controller method that at the end calls render on view. If You simply call `return view('something')` it's not enough. So please add full controller action body.

Comment: old value is called flash input, which exists once and it uses session. so at least You've to have some kind of  `session()->flashInput($request->input()); return view('viewname');`

Comment: Look at your validation, all you have is required. So if your data is empty and gives your `field is required` then how can you expect old data ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#old-input

Comment: I just written this for checking validation. if validation fails. it automatically return back with messages to the form. its laravel default validate method

Comment: i have 10 fields. just 2 is required here.

Comment: so fix Your method that returns it should be like `return redirect()->back()->withInput(Input::all())`

Comment: I know but i think you are not picking up my point. If you haven't input any value and it gives you error that this field is required ? then how you can expect old value ?

Comment: it returns me old input. I just want to check in blade. it exists or not.

Comment: So it's Your fault that You don't have 2 separate method handlers (actions), 1st one should show form, another handler request from form and if it's invalid to redirect back to form with old input. So as @AkhtarMunir said validation will not let You pass if it's empty initially.

Comment: you didn't got my point. I need to check in blade Request::old('status) is null or not?

Comment: @tariqulanik You cannot check old value without passing it as flash value, so please add more controller method code to see whole picture. Your view code is correct, it's `{{ old('status') }}`

Comment: Everything is working. old values are also returns after validation . but for Some of my needs I want to check old() value is null or not

Comment: first time old value is none. but isset() is not working

Comment: fyi check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081644/how-to-redirect-back-to-form-with-input-laravel-5 thereis an answer with validation

Comment: I think should give you the full form. then you will understand

Comment: please check now I include the full form from blade

Comment: check answer if may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can check it in this way. Remember to return it in this way from controller

```
 $validator = $this->validate($request, [
                'type' => 'required',
                'status' => 'required'
              ]);
if ( $validator->fails() ) {
        return back()->withErrors( $validator )->withInput();
    }
```

> In your view do this

```
<select class="select2" name="status">
   <option value="">Please Select</option>
   <option value="Paid" {{ old('status') == 'Paid' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Paid</option>
   <option value="Due" {{ old('status') == 'Due' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Due</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @if($errors->any())
    <option style="display: none" value="{{old('status')}}" hidden>{{old('status')}}</option>
@endif

Comment: it works. but display:none is not working after checking

Comment: Lolz yeah its me, what happened again ? 