# How to access form input after validation failure in Laravel 7

Tags: validation, laravel-7

I'm using Laravel 7 with a validator facade to validate a form submission. Validation is working correctly; however I don't see where to access the old form information to re-populate the fields that the user already filled out. I can see the errors passed by `->withErrors()`, but I don't see any input from `->withInput()`.

This is in my controller method:
// validate the responses
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
'question_1' => 'required',
'question_2' => 'required',
'question_3' => 'required',
'question_4' => 'required',
'question_5' => 'required',
]);

```
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }
```

However, when I debug the variables in the template, I don't see the old input data:

```
@if($errors->any())
        {{ dd(  get_defined_vars()['__data'] ) }}

    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        {{ $error }}<br/>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

---

```
array:4 [▼
  "__env" => Illuminate\View\Factory {#290 ▶}
  "app" => Illuminate\Foundation\Application {#2 ▶}
  "errors" => Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag {#351 ▶}
  "questions" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1319 ▶}
]
```

In the above debugging output, I get the `errors` key with my error messages, but I don't see the old input anywhere in the variables. The `questions` key is the collection of database results passed to the template, not the old input.

How do I access the old form input that a user submitted, after a validation failure?

Answer (score 1):

This is smiler question and ther is useful answers :
[How to redirect back to form with input - Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31081644/9351021)
You can use :

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput(Input::all())
```

In your HTML you have to use `value = {{ old('') }}`. Without using it, you can't get the value back because what session will store in their cache.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{old('name') }}" />
```